# Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration. in angular problem with ts

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, web

please help me out with the countdown timer

the error which I am getting for now is as follows:
Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.

this is from app.component.html

```
<div app-landing>

</div>
```

this is the html code

```
<div class="container">

    <!-- LEFT SIDE -->


    <div class="split left" id="upComing">
        <h1 id="uce">THE UPCOMING EVENT</h1>
        <table id="tableTimer">
            <tr id="timerValue">
                <td id="days"></td>
                <td id="hrs"></td>
                <td id="mins"></td>
                <td id="secs"></td>

            </tr>
            <tr id="timerSub">
                <td>Days</td>
                <td>Hours</td>
                <td>Minutes</td>
                <td>Seconds</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>


    <!-- RIGHT SIDE -->


    <div class="split right" id="nextFive">
        <h1 id="nfe">THE NEXT FIVE EVENTS</h1>
        <table>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="footer" id="footer"></div>
```

this is the the ts file. I am totally new to angular and TS , help me solve the issue 
want to display a countdown timer in side a table . and can't do .

```
    enter code hereimport { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[app-landing]',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.css']
})
export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  countDown() {
    var today, eventDay, currentTime, eventTime, remainTime, sec, min, hr, days;

    today = new Date();
    eventDay = new Date();

    currentTime = today.getTime();
    eventTime = eventDay.getTime();

    remainTime = eventTime - currentTime;
    sec = Math.floor(remainTime / 1000);
    min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    hr = Math.floor(min / 60);
    days = Math.floor(hr / 24);

    hr %= 24;
    min %= 60;
    sec %= 60;

    hr = (hr < 10) ? '0' + hr : hr;
    min = (min < 10) ? '0' + min : min;
    sec = (sec < 10) ? '0' + sec : sec;

    document.getElementById('days').innerText = days;
    document.getElementById('days').textContent = days + '' + ':';
    document.getElementById('hrs').textContent = hr + '' + ':';
    document.getElementById('mins').textContent = min + '' + ':';
    document.getElementById('secs').textContent = sec;

    setInterval(this.countDown, 1000);


}

countDown();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You are calling `countdown()` in the body of the component class. This isn't valid javascript. You chould call `this.countdown();` from ngOnInit().

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.countdown();
}
```

ngOnInit is part of the Angular framework, and run by Angular upon the component being loaded if it exists.

2. You are manually manipulating the DOM. This isn't the "Angular way". Instead you update your model (properties on the component), and bind to the model in your HTML to update the DOM.

**html**

```
<!-- instead of -->
<td id="days"></td>

<!-- bind read-only values using interpolation -->
<td>{{days}}</td>
```

**ts**

```
days: number;

countdown(): void {
    const today = new Date();
    const eventDay = new Date();

    const currentTime = today.getTime();
    const eventTime = eventDay.getTime();

    const remainTime = eventTime - currentTime;

    let sec = Math.floor(remainTime / 1000);
    let min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    let hr = Math.floor(min / 60);
    let days = Math.floor(hr / 24);

    hr %= 24;
    min %= 60;
    sec %= 60;

    hr = (hr < 10) ? '0' + hr : hr;
    min = (min < 10) ? '0' + min : min;
    sec = (sec < 10) ? '0' + sec : sec;

    this.days = days;

    // TODO: add and set the other properties

    setInterval(() => this.countDown(), 1000);
}
```

EDIT

You should follow the official Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial. It's a great starting point.

Comment: thank you so much I fixed it as u told .the countdown timer is not changing by itself can you u please help me with that

Comment: I would recommend adding what you have done so far to a stackblitz, and then it becomes much easier to tweak what you have done: https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: can u please tell me how to open up the termial in the link u have provided

Comment: If you want to add dependencies, go to the bottom left hand corner, below files. You generally can't get to the terminal in cloud-based editors

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8qafu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fland%2Flanding.component.ts

Comment: I've updated your stackblitz. I moved the countdown into app component to avoid messing around with routing. I'm also using setTimeout instead of setInterval so that countdown() ends up only scheduling itself once. You could use setInterval in ngOnInit. You could also use rxjs's interval.

Answer (score 0):

simple change your code like this

ts file

```
  ngOnInit(){
   this.countDown();
  }
  timer={days:'',hr:'',min:'',sec:''}


   countDown() {
    var today, eventDay, currentTime, eventTime, remainTime, sec, min, hr, days;
    window.setInterval(()=>{
    today = new Date();
    eventDay = new Date('2020-02-14');
    currentTime = today.getTime();
    eventTime = eventDay.getTime();

    remainTime = eventTime - currentTime;
    sec = Math.floor(remainTime / 1000);
    min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
    hr = Math.floor(min / 60);
    days = Math.floor(hr / 24);
    hr %= 24;
    min %= 60;
    sec %= 60;
   this.timer={sec,days,min,hr}

 }
```

in your html like this

```
<div class="container">

<!-- LEFT SIDE -->


<div class="split left" id="upComing">
    <h1 id="uce">THE UPCOMING EVENT</h1>
    <table id="tableTimer">
        <tr id="timerValue">
            <td id="days">{{timer.days}}</td>
            <td id="hrs">{{timer.hr}}</td>
            <td id="mins">{{timer.min}}</td>
            <td id="secs">{{timer.sec}}</td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="timerSub">
            <td>Days</td>
            <td>Hours</td>
            <td>Minutes</td>
            <td>Seconds</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


<!-- RIGHT SIDE -->


<div class="split right" id="nextFive">
    <h1 id="nfe">THE NEXT FIVE EVENTS</h1>
    <table>

    </table>
</div>
```